# Form won't send to the MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php require_once('../../config/auth.php');
include "../../config/connection.php";

$rank = $_SESSION['SESS_USER_RANK'];

if ($rank == 0){

header("location: ../../errors/606.php");
exit();

}

$custom = $_POST['name'];
$ulx = $_POST['ulx'];
$price = $_POST['price'];
$desc = $_POST['desc'];


$addrank = "INSERT INTO ranks (rank_name, rank_ulx_name, rank_price, pr_desc)
VALUES ('$custom', '$ulx', '$price', '$desc',)";
mysql_query($addrank);

header("location: ../../editranks.php");
exit();
?>

    <h4>Add Custom Rank</h4>

            <table class="table table-hover table-hover">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Rank Name</th>
              <th>Ulx Name</th>
                     <th>Price</th>
              <th>Description</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>

   <form method="post" action="functions/admin/addrank.php"><tr>

   <td style="width: 14%;"><input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" value=""></td>
   <td style="width: 14%;"><input class="form-control" type="text" name="ulx" value=""></td>
   <td style="width: 14%;"><input class="form-control" type="text" name="price" value=""></td>
   <td style="width: 15%;"><input class="form-control" type="text" name="desc" value=""></td>
                  <td style="width: 11%;"><input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Add Rank!"></a></td>

                </tr></form>  



                        </tbody>
        </table>
```

Right so, the code is above and when I try and add a rank, it doesn't do anything. Flat out, just refreshes the page pretty mcuh and nothing shows. I can go into PhpMyAdmin and add things manually to each catagory that is already in the database. But other than that, it doesn't work. I don't get any errors and the form does show up, but nothing happens when I send. Any help would be great, I am not an expert in MySQl/PHP so this is what I have. Thanks!

Comment: You are vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), and are simply assuming your code is perfect.  You need to have `$result = mysql_query($addrank) or die(mysql_error());` as a bare minimum error handling system.

Comment: Please don't insert raw input data into your database without validating it. At the very least, please use the mysql_real_escape_string() function escape out single quotes. Also, mysql_* functions have been deprecated as of PHP 5.5. Look into using mysqli or PDO. Examples can be seen on the official PHP manual. [link](http://php.net)

Comment: Didn't think I was assuming my code is perfect xD As I said, I am not an expert, I've only just started really. Thank you though for the comments, I will edit acoordingly.

Comment: If [`the answer`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22544464/) that has been provided for you below has solved your problem, and to close the question and be marked as answered, click the White checkmark till it turns Green. @FireGriffin If it did not solve it, let me know.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the last comma in `'$desc',`

```
('$custom', '$ulx', '$price', '$desc')
```

Also, do [`read this article`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/) regarding SQL injection.

Using [`mysqli_*`](http://php.net/mysqli) functions: (which I recommend you use and with [**prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO**](http://php.net/pdo))

```
$custom = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['name']); // etc.
```

`$con` being a DB connection variable once you do (*hopefully*) move over to using.

as an example.

`mysql_*` functions are deprecated and will be removed from future PHP releases.

---

Here are a few tutorials on prepared statements that you can study and try:

- [**Tutorial one**](http://webdevtuts.co.uk/simple-mysqli-tutorial/#more-41)
- [**Tutorial two**](http://www.tutorialized.com/tutorial/PHP-5:-MySQLi-Prepared-Statements/41452)
- [**Tutorial three**](http://www.phpmysqlitutorials.com/2011/04/16/mysqli-whats-the-difference-between-standard-queries-and-prepared-statements/)

Here are a few tutorials on PDO:

- [**PDO tutorial one**](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html)
- [**PDO tutorial two**](http://crewow.com/PHP-PDO-to-Connect-MySQL-Database.php)
- [**PDO tutorial three**](http://www.w3resource.com/php/pdo/php-pdo.php)

(*A look ahead*) Should you ever decide to get into using password storage later on (*many do*), I recommend that you use one of the following (*although there are others*):

- [`crypt()`](http://php.net/crypt)
- [`PHP 5.5 password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function